# Win 10 PC Randomly Freezing (Dead Locked)

Tags: windows-10, freeze

Looking for suggestions on how to resolve an issue I have here with an older desktop PC that is running Win 10.

For a few weeks now, the desktop PC is randomly freezing, as in: it is dead locked. The Win desktop is still visible (in a frozen state), but it does not take any keyboard or mouse commands. The freeze also happens when the PC was just idling (no program running).
When music was playing when the freeze kicks in, then sound oscillation or stuttering occurs while the freeze is happening.

Have to cold reboot the PC. Have not found a way to force trigger it, as in: being able to re-create the problem with a specific action or series of actions, it just happens randomly.

Notes:

(a) BIOS settings were not changed in years

(b) hardware was not changed in years

(c) no recent software install

Here's what I tried so far:

(1) ran full chkdsk on all drives (incl OS drive) - zero errors found

(2) ran Memtest86 5.01 and MemTest86 v4.3.7, each over 10 passes - no errors

also ran Win built-in memory test, no errors.

(3) re-seated all RAM sticks and PCIe cards

(4) replaced SATA cables to all drives/devices, odd enough this seemed to have helped a bit initially but we're back to freezing

(5) replaced OS drive - did not help

(6) re-installed Win 10 in a clean, new install - still freezing

(7) recovered from an older Acronis backup, still freezing

What should I do next ? Replace PSU, Mobo, GPU (which involves buying new parts) or is there anything else I should try first?

Comment: Randomly replacing hardware is not an efficient way to resolve an issue.  Check if it's a hardware issue by running from another OS, without using SSD or HDD. For example, create a bootable USB flash drive with WinPE or Ubuntu (https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). If that boots and works for a few days without crashing, then it's a hardware, OS, or BIOS setting issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik appreciate the input. I'm not sure I follow or agree, but possibly I misunderstand your comment. The only thing that running from a bootable drive would prove is that the OS drive is bad, which I already replaced during testing. If it is a GPU, RAM or mobo issue, the symptoms would still occur but we still would not know which hardware part is at fault, which is what I currently need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Static image with short-loop audio is likely a graphics issue - however, it signifies *either* over-heat or under-power & it's hard to determine which.

Clean the entire machine right down & replace any thermal paste, including on the graphics card GPU heat sink… which isn't always an easy task.

It might be as simple as old, tired paste - or it might be the PSU is getting weak. Do the 'free' fixes first, though.

If you have a spare graphics card, try that too.